# How to change UILabel font size after changing font size from Settting screen

Tags: iphone

When I am changing my font size from Setting screen it is not affecting my UILabel and UITextbox font size in my application.

What I need to do for taking of defined font size of application?
Or is there any flag exist in Interface builder so component would change whenever user will change font size ration from setting screen?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set font of label using preferredFontForTextStyle method.

Check out this tutorial
http://www.raywenderlich.com/50151/text-kit-tutorial